# Rufus scheduler not running in production puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I have a puma running in production.

```
threads 1,1
workers 3
preload_app!
```

This is the puma configuration.However only one instance Rufus-scheduler is working perfectly running in development environment as expected.

I am running on Rails 4.0.2

Any reasons why this can't be running?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/183 can help (just googled "puma rufus-scheduler") to find it.

Comment: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html